# How to block AppEngine's _ah/start and _ah/stop routes from being visible to the outside world

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I have _ah/start and _ah/stop routes in my 'Flexible' app. I understand the GAE containers will invoke those endpoints when the app comes up, and is going down.

After I've deployed my app, I can hit them myself from the comfort of my couch. **That makes no sense of course, as random strangers cannot be the arbiter of when app instances come up and go down**.  How do I configure AppEngine to block the publication of those two routes to the outside world?  Or is in my job in the implementation of those two routes to check IP addresses or look for a header only GAE can send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So flex does not use the /_ah/* paths and therefore does not hide them.  Sadly we have an inconsistency in our docs.  It is correctly documented here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating but (at the moment) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build is incorrect.  The documentation update is under review and should go public shortly.

Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for being frank - keep up with the good work. I think I'll code a traditional shutdown hook

Comment: The public docs are now up to date - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build

Comment: I'm confused, Frank.  I've just taken a look and the section 'Health check requests' implies that _ah/health does work for flex.  Kinda goes against your "So flex does not use the /_ah/*" statement.

Comment: Hi Paul.  You're correct '/_ah/health' is still used for health checks.  It's also not blocked.

Comment: Hi Zach - what about `/_ah/stop`? Is that blocked? If not, I can see problems if a random stranger hit that endpoint on an application that had code attached to that route, where the author THOUGHT that on Google's container infra could invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this page:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled

Headers that match `X-Google-*` or `X-Appengine-*` are removed when the request enters GCP. Appengine may then add headers that match those patterns, so if your handlers detect any such headers I think it is safe to assume the request comes from GAE and not some random client.

You can dump all headers you get and see whether there are any interesting ones, then from a public client try and send a request and set such a header with some value and see whether it is sanitized first and then set again by GAE. Any such header **must be sanitized** first or anyone would be able to send them to your app otherwise.

I would not rely on IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

So i struggled a bit to really understand how the `/_ah/stop` actually worked, the doc is unclear, I'm adding an answer to this post for further reference because it's the one that pops up first in Google searches.

The `/_ah/stop` endpoint only applies to **standard instances, using manual scaling** (it's in the last column of the table here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed which applies to **manual scaling only**, which is not trivial at first glance).

In my usecase I had an app with two services, an API (automatic scaling) and a Worker (manual scaling), and I freaked out because I could call the `/_ah/stop` route on my API, thus killing it. It works properly with my worker, because, in this usecase the route is protected by GAE.

If anyone from GAE team reads this post, maybe that would be good to block routes `/_ah/*` in any contexts, because I now fear that one day we'll switch to another kind of environment and we'll expose us to potential security threats if we forget to change the config.

Hope it'll help.